# Error "path.merge is not a function" when creating an axis for bar chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Just as some information, I installed d3, d3-axis, and d3-scale individually as so

```
npm i --save d3
npm i --save d3-axis
npm i --save d3-scale
```

and import then into my file as so

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as scale from "d3-scale";
import * as axis from "d3-axis";
```

When trying to create the xAxis, I keep getting the error as mentioned in the title above. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out and watching Youtube videos and following their work word for work and line by line. Still, no luck. Can anyone help me? I assume it's because of the d3-axis or d3-scale stuff, but I can't figure it out.

**Current Dummy Code**

```
type Props = {||};

type DummyData = {|
    id: string,
    value: number,
    region: string,
|};

type State = {|
    dummyData: Array<DummyData>,
|};

const WIDTH = 800;
const HEIGHT = 500;
const MARGIN = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180};
const PADDING = 0.1;

class D3BarChart extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
        dummyData: [
            {id: "d1", value: 10, region: "USA"},
            {id: "d2", value: 11, region: "India"},
            {id: "d3", value: 12, region: "China"},
            {id: "d4", value: 6, region: "Germany"},
        ],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const {dummyData} = this.state;

        const xScale = scale
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(dummyData.length))
            .range([MARGIN.left, WIDTH - MARGIN.right])
            .padding(PADDING);

        const yScale = scale
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dummyData, d => d.value)])
            .nice()
            .range([HEIGHT - MARGIN.bottom, MARGIN.top]);

        const xAxis = g =>
            g.attr("transform", `translate(0,${HEIGHT - MARGIN.bottom})`).call(
                axis
                    .axisBottom(xScale)
                    .tickFormat(i => data[i].name)
                    .tickSizeOuter(0),
            );

        const yAxis = g => g =>
            g
                .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.left},0)`)
                .call(axis.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(null, data.format))
                .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
                .call(g =>
                    g
                        .append("text")
                        .attr("x", -MARGIN.left)
                        .attr("y", 10)
                        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                        .text(data.y),
                );

        const svg = d3
            .select("#test")
            .insert("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(dummyData)
            .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
            .attr("y", d => yScale(d.value))
            .attr("height", d => yScale(0) - yScale(d.value))
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth());

        svg.append("g").call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g").call(yAxis);

        svg.node();
    }

    render(): React.Node {
        return (
            <View>
                <LabelLarge>{i18n.doNotTranslate("D3.js")}</LabelLarge>
                <Strut size={Spacing.xLarge_32} />
                <div id="test"></div>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Not sure what the Typescript and React boilerplate required is to reproduce. Can you please create a Codesandbox or some minimal, live reproduction?

Comment: @MGO I am unsure exactly how to do that :( From the code is there anything that seems... off? It seems like it should work, but not getting any luck here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-allen-jw9im?file=/src/D3BarChart.js:1865-2194&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to reproduce the issue with the Typescript boilerplate that specific error is a little tough to diagnose.

[**There is a working, slightly refactored version of your code with a class-based React component here.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-allen-jw9im?file=/src/D3BarChart.js:1865-2194&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800)

But based on the comment "does anything look off?", there are a couple of things that jumped out in the snippet.

1. You shouldn't need to import `scale` and `axis` individually. Use `import * from 'd3' as d3`, and call the `scale` and `axis` methods from the `d3` object.
2. Directly appending to `document` seems like it might be an anti-pattern and may cause problems. Suggest avoiding that if you can.
3. The y-axis won't render as written `yAxis = (g) => (g) =>`. Change that to

```
const yAxis = (g) =>

     g
       .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.left},0)`)
       .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(null, dummyData.format))
       .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
       .call(
         (g) =>
           g
             .append("text")
             .attr("x", -MARGIN.left)
             .attr("y", 10)
             .attr("fill", "currentColor")
             .attr("text-anchor", "start")
         // .text(dummyData.y)
       );
```

and your y-axis will render.

4. Call the `scale` and `axis` functions directly from `d3`, like this:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(dummyData.length))
            .range([MARGIN.left, WIDTH - MARGIN.right])
            .padding(PADDING);

        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dummyData, d => d.value)])
            .nice()
            .range([HEIGHT - MARGIN.bottom, MARGIN.top]);
```

5. Appending a `g` to your `svg` will not render any bars. (See screenshot).

[image]

You'll need to create the DOM element to allow D3 to bind your data
to, like this:

```
 svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
      .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.value))
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", (d) => yScale(0) - yScale(d.value));
```

That will render your bars:

[image]

Lastly, even if you do choose to stay with a class-based component approach (as opposed to React Hooks), do consider using a `ref`, since since D3 may accidentally interact with unrelated components or DOM elements, such as when other components have elements with the same class being selected.

Using a `ref` should guarantee the correct selection, and is generally  the preferred pattern.

[It's a hooks based approach, but I think it's worth checking out Amelia Wattenberger's blog post on this for more detail.](https://wattenberger.com/blog/react-and-d3)

Again, [**working code is here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-allen-jw9im?file=/src/D3BarChart.js:1865-2194&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800), feel free to fork and use if it's useful for you.

Hope this is helpful! ✌️

Answer (score -1):

Not the best solution, but using the script tag in your body instead of using `npm i d3 d3-axis d3-scale` fixed the problem very quick.

To do this with React, you can do it in `componentDidMount` or `useEffect`.

```
componentDidMount() {
   const script = document.createElement("script");

   script.src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js";
   script.async = true;

   document.body && document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```